# Property of a Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\big(\Bbb R,\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*,\overline{\lambda}\big)$ be a lebesgue (complete) measure space and let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a lebesgue measurable function.

$$\text{I want to guarantee there exists}\;\; M>0\;\; \text{s.t.}\;\; \overline{\lambda}\big(\{x\in\Bbb R:|f(x)|\le M\}\big)>0$$

But the only I've got so far is that $\{x\in\Bbb R:|f(x)|\le M\}=f^{-1}\big([-M,M]\big)\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$, since $f$ is measurable.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with $f$...

Comment: Thanks, forgot to write preimage. I have edit it.

Comment: Why do you write $\bar \lambda?$

Comment: No, $f$ doesn't have to go anywhere near zero, you could have $f$ identically equal to $1$ for example.

Comment: Ok, so instead could it be possible to find a bounded set $A\in A_{\Bbb R}^*$ s.t. $\overline{\lambda}(f^{-1}(A))>0)\;$?

And @zhw, by $\overline{\lambda}$ I mean the Lebesgue complete measure: 

$$\overline{\lambda}:\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*\to [0,\infty]\\
\text{where}\;\;\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*\;\;\text{is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets}$$

Comment: I want to guarantee that I can find $M>0$ s.t. 
$$\overline{\lambda}\big(\{x\in\Bbb R:|f(x)|\le M\}\big)>0$$
but the only thing I can see is that:

$$f^{-1}([-M,M])=\{x\in\Bbb R:|f(x)|\le M\}\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$$
since $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Hint: $$\bigcup_{M=1}^\infty \{ x\in\Bbb R \colon |f(x)|\le M \} = \Bbb R.$$

Comment: @GregMartin So, since $\Bbb R\ne\emptyset$, $\;\;\exists\ M>0$ s.t. $x\in\{x\in\Bbb R: |f(x)|\le M\}$ for any fixed $x\in\Bbb R$ and thus $\overline{\lambda}\big(\{x\in\Bbb R: |f(x)|\le M\}\big)>0$

Comment: More precisely, if $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \cdots$ then $\bar\lambda(\bigcup_{M=1}^\infty S_M) = \lim_{M\to\infty} \bar\lambda(S_M)$. (This is a consequence of disjoint additivity of $\bar\lambda$, setting $T_1=S_1$ and $T_k=S_k\setminus S_{k-1}$ for $k\ge2$.)

Comment: Ok, but how does this helps to the fact that I can get an $M>0$ s.t. $\overline{\lambda}(S_M)>0$?